# median plotted together with time courses for multiple subjects in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, median

I have the following data frame with time courses Y1 for 10 subjects. Each subjest has one numeric, one non-numeric label

```
      Sub Time Y1   lab1 lab2
1     1   0.0  0.0  40   weak
2     1   0.5  1.1  40   weak
...
10    1   63   2.0  40   weak
...
91    10  0.0  0.0  23   strong
92    10  0.5  1.2  23   strong
...
100   10  63   1.6  23   strong
```

I would like to compute the Y1 median for all subjects, group-wise i.e. for weak/strong subgroups, and to plot them together with Y1 time series in one figure.

However, the main issue is the median. If I unstack/spread the dataframe using

```
DF2 <- unstack(DF1, Y1~Sub)
```

I can then easily calculate the median with `rowMedians` but I cannot merge it with ggplot-ed time series for single subjects because of dimensional differences. To be more precise if I do that

```
  p1 <- ggplot(data = DF1, 
           mapping=aes(x = DF1$Time, y = DF1$Y1, group=DF1$Index)) +
        geom_line(aes(color=DF1$lab2)) +
        geom_line(data = medianDF, aes(x=medianDF$time,y=medianDF$median))
```

I get the error message: `Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (10): group`.
Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you give us a sample of your code using `dput`?

Comment: Never use `data$column` inside `aes()`, just use the unquoted column names. Change to `aes(x =Time, y = Y1, group=Index)`, etc. And maybe set `inherit.aes= FALSE` for the layer with `medianDF`. If that doesn't work, we'll need some reproducible data to debug.

Comment: Move the `group` aesthetic next to `color`. (And indeed never `$` inside `aes`.)

Comment: Moving `group` aesthetic next to `color` did the trick. Thanks for all the comments!